# JPG encoding in python sent via socket to C# and decode

Tags: c#, python, sockets, stream, jpeg

I want to sent my processed image from python backend to C# frontend.
So i encode it using JPG encoder and sent.

When i receive it and decoding it using jpegdecoder in C#, it throw the exception. Where size of received bytes are equal to the bytes sent after encoding.

Could anyone guide me how i decode this image and display it.

code in Python Server Side encoding Image JPG

```
while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print ('connected to : ' + addr[0] +" :"+ str(addr[1])) 

    vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(videoPath)
    total_frames = int(vidcap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
    conn.setblocking(0)
    for mm in range(0,total_frames ,1):
       try:
           dataClient = str(conn.recv(4096).decode('UTF-8'))
           conn.send(str.encode(dataClient))   
           conn.close()
           kk=2
           break
       except socket.error:

           ret,img= vidcap.read()
           image = cv2.resize(img, (640, 480)) 
           #############################################
           encode_param=[int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY),100]
           result,enData=cv2.imencode('.jpg',image,encode_param)
           conn.send(enData)
           #############################################
```

Code in C# Client side decoding Image JPG

```
            const int PORT_NO = 6666;
            //const string SERVER_IP = "210.107.232.138"; // 210.107.232.138          127.0.0.1
            string SERVER_IP = IpAddress.Text;
            client = new TcpClient(SERVER_IP, PORT_NO);
            nwStream = client.GetStream();
            bytesToRead = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
            bytesRead = nwStream.Read(bytesToRead, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
            /////////////////////////////////////
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytesRead);
            JpegBitmapDecoder decoder = new JpegBitmapDecoder(ms, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.Default); //line 129
            BitmapSource bitmapSource = decoder.Frames[0];
            ///////////////////////////////////// 
            var src = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.FormatConvertedBitmap();
            src.BeginInit();
            src.Source = bitmapSource;
            src.DestinationFormat = System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Bgra32;
            src.EndInit();

            //copy to bitmap
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(src.PixelWidth, src.PixelHeight, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            var data = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bitmap.Size), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            src.CopyPixels(System.Windows.Int32Rect.Empty, data.Scan0, data.Height * data.Stride, data.Stride);
            bitmap.UnlockBits(data);

            pictureBox2.Image = bitmap;
```

[image: Exception]

Comment: What if bytesRead is less than the bytes sent by your Python code? There's no guarantee you will receive the full buffer of data in a single receive event. Also, is there a reason why you can't just use the `Image.FromStream(...)` method?

Comment: I try this also but it doesn't work also

Comment: You put nothing into the MemoryStream. You just initialize it with the size that's determined by `bytesRead`. You probably want to use `new MemoryStream(bytesToRead)`?

Comment: i check the size of bytes on both sides. these are same.

Comment: nwStream = client.GetStream();
                bytesToRead = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
                bytesRead = nwStream.Read(bytesToRead, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);

                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytesRead);

Comment: Read my comment again. Your problem is not the receiving (while it is somewhat flawed as john points out already). Your MemoryStream is empty. You are using this constructor: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bx3c0489(v=vs.110).aspx but you need this one: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e55f3s5k(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: How my memoryStream is empty?. i passed byte array to it.

Comment: _"How my memoryStream is empty?. i passed byte array to it."_ No you didn't. At least not in the snippet from the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytesRead); // bytesRead = int, number of bytes received
```

This line creates an **empty** MemoryStream with an initial capacity of `bytesRead` bytes. See [MemoryStream(int)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bx3c0489(v=vs.110).aspx)

You need to use another constructor to also fill it with the received data:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytesToRead); // byte[], received data
```

See [MemoryStream(Byte[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e55f3s5k(v=vs.110).aspx)

---

Please also mind john's comment on your receiving code:

> There's no guarantee you will receive the full buffer of data in a single receive event.

Comment: My code is time event it is not in receiving in single event. `private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {       nwStream = client.GetStream();
                bytesToRead = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
                bytesRead = nwStream.Read(bytesToRead, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytesRead);
                JpegBitmapDecoder decoder = new JpegBitmapDecoder(ms, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.Default);
                BitmapSource bitmapSource = decoder.Frames[0];
        }`

Comment: Ignore that part for now. **Just try replacing bytesRead with bytesToRead in the MemoryStream CTOR** and see what happens ...

Comment: Yes it work i receive first image but it is half. id don't know why.

Comment: That's a different question ;)

Answer (score 4):

`TcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize` has a [default value 8KB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.receivebuffersize(v=vs.110).aspx). If your jpeg data has more bytes than that, since your c# code just read the buffer only once, you will not receive the whole data.

You maybe want to use a loop in your c# code to read until reach the end of tcp stream.

try this:

```cs
var ms = new MemoryStream();
var buff = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
while (true) {
    var len = nwStream.Read(buff, 0, buff.Length);
    if (len <= 0) { break; }
    ms.Write(buff, 0, len);
}
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

wish helps.

Comment: The size of data after encoding is 161183 bytes. Which almost 1.5kb

Comment: @AminUllah The size is not your primary problem right now. It may be one in the future when you handle images > 8kB. But that's a different question and needs a different solution.

Comment: @AminUllah that's about 16KB.

Comment: @YunLuo 161183 / 1024 = 157.4 (rounded)

Comment: @Fildor :) about 160KB, my mistake, but still, far more than 8KB.

Comment: @YunLuo Yes. The problem will still remain if OP fixes his receiving code, though. Using *your* snippet it should work, however.